# Rephrasing "the Lord's our Banner"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

How to rephrase "the Lord's our Banner" for kids to understand referring to the story of Moses praying for Joshua to win the battle in Exodus 17:10-15.

I am thinking of "God gives us victory" or "He leads us to win".  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that in the context of Exo 17:14, the word "Jehovahnissi" is not a proverb or exclamation; it's what Jacob has *named* the altar. So I think any new translation of it should fit in that context. I'd recommend "***God's Victory***", because (1) it is attributing and giving up the actual victory to god (as Joshua intends, and the *giving-up* sense is appropriate to an altar) and (2) it follows the modern convention of naming things after their patron: God's Victory could easily be the name of a modern warship, for example (in a non-secular state, of course).

Comment: If I remember rightly, if attackers managed to capture a legion's standard, they'd won. The expression 'fight for the flag' shows that 'the flag' is still regarded as vital, but nowadays the metonymic significance (flag standing for nation, friends, family, identity, existence, wellbeing, wealth ...) is probably better understood intellectually (though not necessarily in the heart). 'God is our everything!' And it's not bad when the Flag fights for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following [extract](http://jehovahroi.wordpress.com/2007/06/19/jehovah-nissi-the-lord-our-banner/) may help:

> - When I think of a banner I think of a big sign or flag waving on display for all to see.  For example, in a parade you will see people carrying a large banner with the name of their group on it so that everyone knows who is following them.  However **in the case of Exodus 17, God went before Moses as his banner so that the people knew who Moses was following and who was leading him!**  In this instance, The Banner is more important than what is following it.  If we follow God, let Him be our banner, and carry Him before us at all times, He will direct our paths, He will make a way for us, He will lead us on the battlefield and He will stand with us always.

I think that you may rephrase as:

- God shows us the Way to Salvation.

Comment: Thanks Dan and Josh for your recommendations.  God's victory and His leading, makes me think of putting it as "The Lord leads us to win." Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom is "under the banner of."

It has two distinctive meanings, both relevent here.

1. Support, protection
2. Cause, objective

Thus,

1. The Lord takes care of us -- supports and protects us.
2. This is God's work -- Our actions are to serve the Lord; for a cause, which is the Lord himself.